# Bound on $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2}$

Tags: summation, digamma-function

I am trying to find a tight bound on the following sum:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n   \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2}
\end{align}

If we use Wolfram_Alpha, we can actually find a closed-form expression:
\begin{align}
\sum_{i=1}^n   \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2}=\gamma+\psi(1-n)+\frac{1}{n}
\end{align}
where $\gamma$ is Euler constant and $\psi$ is the digamma function.   The exact result is a bit confusing to me. Specifically,  I never seen the digamma function for negative integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint :**
$$\sum_{i=1}^n   \sum_{k=1}^i \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n   \sum_{i=k}^n \frac{1}{(n-k+1)^2}  = \sum_{k=1}^n    \frac{n-k+1}{(n-k+1)^2} = \sum_{k=1}^n    \frac{1}{n-k+1}$$

Comment: Can you explain the first step? The rest I follow

Comment: I interverted the two summations, changing the indices : $\sum_{i=1}^n \sum_{k=1}^i a_{ik} = \sum_{k=1}^n \sum_{i=k}^n a_{ik}$.